# Let $R$ be an integral domain. If $I \cap J = IJ$ for all ideals $I,J$ of $R,$ then $R$ is a field.

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be an integral domain. If $I \cap J = IJ$ for all ideals $I,J$ of $R,$ how do I show $R$ is a field? Hints will suffice. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $a\in R\setminus\{0\}$ and consider $I = J = Ra$.

Comment: Haha I got it from that thanks

Comment: Let $r \in R.$ Then $r'a^{2} = ra, $ for some $r' \in R.$ Since $R$ is integral domain, $r = r'a \in Ra.$ So $1 \in Ra$ and hence $a$ is unit.

Comment: Don't you want to take $J$ as $R$ so the intersection will be $(a)$ and the product will be $R$?

Comment: @JohnDouma If $J=R$, then the product will be $Ra$, not $R$.

Comment: @AlexyVincenzo Yes, this is, what I had in mind. Notice that you can assume $r=1$ to begin with.

Comment: @Claudius Thank you. I should have known it wasn't that easy because we wouldn't have needed the fact that $R$ is an integral domain.

Answer (score 1):

*Arithmetically*: since ideal intersection $= \rm lcm$ for principal ideals, the hypothesis implies for all $\,a,b\neq 0\,$ we have $\,{\rm lcm}(a,b) = ab,\,$ so $\,\gcd(a,b)=1,\,$ i.e. $\,a,b$ have only unit common factors. Hence for $\,b=a\,$ the common factor $\,a\,$ of $\,a,b$ is a unit, so $\,a\neq 0\,\Rightarrow\, a\,$ is a unit, so $R$ is a field.

Comment: Essentially we used: $\,0\neq a$ is a unit $\!\iff\! \gcd(a,x) = 1\!\iff\! {\rm lcm}(a,x) = ax,\ $ for all $\,x\neq 0.\ $ Recall that in general domains $\gcd$ and $\rm lcm$ are defined only up to unit factors (associates).